# Single letter command to read files on linux

Tags: bash

We can use several commands to read files such as `cat` or `head` but I have had someone tell me there exists a single letter command to read all files in a directory. Is there truly anything out there or was he pulling my chain?

Comment: Is should be a `script` or an `alias`

Comment: I believe your left leg is currently an inch or two longer than your right leg — courtesy the efforts of your friend.  People could invent an alias or write such a command.  The only standard single-character binary I can think of is `[` (`/bin/[` or `/usr/bin/[`), which is also a shell built-in and more or less a synonym for `test`.  (Experiments: on a Mac, there's `w`, a command for listing who's logged on. I've never found that I needed to use it — I tend to use `who` directly.)

Answer (score 0):

You can try yourself:

```
#! /bin/bash
for char in {a..z} {A..Z} ; do
    $char
done
```

Maybe there's an alias defined, but commands tend to be a bit longer to increase redundancy to avoid typos.

Comment: Well, that would match /usr/bin/X and /usr/bin/w in some systems. R might be installed, too.

Comment: @JamesBrown: It catches X for me, too.